# Thinkster MEAN stack tutorial, deletion of element

Tags: angularjs, json, mean-stack

I've been following the Thinkster Mean Stack tutorial, and it works wonderfully. So I have created my own project, and so far everything works fine.
However, they didn't cover how to delete posts. 
And I can for the life for me not figure out how to delete an element from the data.

AngularApp.js

```
var app = angular.module('KOL', ['ui.router'])
    .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                url: '/home',
                templateUrl: "/views/home.ejs",
                controller: 'kolCtrl',
                resolve: {
                        patientPromise: ['patients', function(patients) {
                            return patients.getAll();
                        }]
                    }
            })
            .state('details', {
                url: '/details/{id}',
                templateUrl: './views/details.html',
                controller: 'detailsCtrl'
            });

            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
    }])
    .factory('patients', ['$http', function($http){
        var object = {
        patients: []               

       };

        object.getAll = function() {
            return $http.get('/patients').success(function(data) {
                angular.copy(data, object.patients);
            });
        }

        object.create = function(patient) {
        return $http.post('/patients', patient).success(function(data){
            object.patients.push(data);
        });
    }


    };
        return object;
    }])
    .controller('kolCtrl', ['$scope', 'patients', 
        function($scope, patients){

              $scope.patients = patients.patients;
              $scope.selectedItem = $scope.patients[0];


              $scope.addPost = function() {
                if(!$scope.title || $scope.title === '') { return; }
                if(!$scope.age || $scope.age === '') { return; }
                patients.create({
                    name: $scope.title,
                    age: $scope.age,
                })

                $scope.title = '';
                $scope.age = '';

              };



              object.delete = function(patient)            

    }])
    .controller('detailsCtrl', [
        '$scope',
        '$stateParams',
        'patients',
        function($scope, $stateParams, patients){


        $scope.patient = patients.patients[$stateParams.id];
    }])


;
```

Home.ejs

```
<div class="container">
        <div clas="row">

            <div style="width: 200px; margin-top: 100px">
            <select  ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="patients.name for patients in patients" class="pull-left form-control" name="Vælg"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="viewbox pull-right">
                <h3>Patient: {{selectedItem.name}}</h3>
                <p>Age: {{selectedItem.age}} </p>
                <p>index: {{patients.indexOf(selectedItem)}}</p>
                <button><a href="#/details/{{patients.indexOf(selectedItem)}}">Rediger</a></button>
                <button ng-click="deleteItem(patients.indexOf(selectedItem))">Delete</button>
            </div>





        </div>
        <div class="row" class="pull-left">
            <div style="width: 200px; margin-top: 100px">
            <form  role="form" class="form-group" ng-submit="addPost()">
                <input  class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="title" />
                <input  class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="age" />
                <button type="submit">Add</button>
            </form>
            </form>
        </div>
     </div>
     </div>
```

index.js (route get and post)

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();



/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Patient = mongoose.model('Patient');

router.get('/patients', function(req, res, next) {
  Patient.find(function(err, patients){
    if(err){ return next(err); }

    res.json(patients);
  });
});

router.post('/patients', function(req, res, next) {
  var patient = new Patient(req.body);

  patient.save(function(err, post){
    if(err){ return next(err); }

    res.json(patient);
  });
});

router.delete('/patients/:patient', function(req, res, next) {
    req.patient.remove(function(err, patient){
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      res.json(patient);
    });
});

router.param('patient', function(req, res, next, id) {
  var query = Patient.findById(id);

  query.exec(function (err, patient){
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (!post) { return next(new Error('can\'t find patient')); }

    req.patient = patient;
    return next();
  });
});

router.get('/details/:patient', function(req, res) {
  res.json(req.patient);
});

module.exports = router;
```

I suspect the answer is quite straightforward, given the other code, but maybe not? 
Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us the js file that is handling your requests? You've posted the angularjs file but show us the node.js/express.js file that should have your get and post functions.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I edited so it now contains the index.js, which contains the routes. Does this help?

Answer (score 1):

According to your function that you are passing to the `router.delete` in your `index.js` file:

```
router.delete('/patients/:patient', function(req, res, next) {
    req.patient.remove(function(err, patient){
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      res.json(patient);
    });
});
```

You'll have to append the `patients.id` to the url when using the `delete` verb with the `$http` service. So you can add a `delete` method to the object in your patients factory:

```
.factory('patients', ['$http', function($http){
    var object = {
    patients: []               

   };

    object.getAll = function() {
        return $http.get('/patients').success(function(data) {
            angular.copy(data, object.patients);
        });
    }

    object.create = function(patient) {
    return $http.post('/patients', patient).success(function(data){
        object.patients.push(data);
    });
    }

    //add patient id to the url
    object.delete = function(patient) {
    return $http.delete('/patients/',patient).success(function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
    }
}


};
    return object;
}])
```

Comment: It says I can't do a function(patient.id) (Unexpected token)

Comment: Well, it now says: object.delete = function(patient.id), but it throws an error in the console.log when I refresh the page (Unexpected token . on line 40) Line 40 is object.delete = function(patient.id). Can this  be right?

Comment: I think part of the problem, is that the index of the element(the mongodb _id) isn't passed from the ng-click to the controller

Comment: I think I need the last part of the solution. I need the specific patient from the home.ejs ng-click to pass into a $scope.deletePatient. How do I go about that?
I hope this is not too much trouble, I really appreciate this.

Comment: Are you able to create and use your post functions correctly? if so? use the same logic when passing the selectedItem to post. If you need further help, try somethings out and then update the question with specifics of what you need help with. Once you can click the button and get one patient, you can pass that patient into the delete method.

Comment: Well, I can add a new patient to the database, but that is outside the select. But I will try as you suggest. Thanks for now, I hope I can fix it! :)

Comment: Thanks, but the thing is, I have no ng-repeat, I only use model. Is it possible to combine them to make the same idea? When I select an item in my input list, it get passed to the viewbox (which uses the ng-models selectedItem)

Comment: Okay! THanks for all the support!

Comment: Hello inspired! I figured out. It has been some battle. But there was a lot of things wrong with my routes, and how they were connected. My ng-model didn't get the _ID because of some faulty setup, but I fixed it. I had to go at it wrong another direction. You want to see the complete solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
 object.delete = function(patient) {
        return $http.delete('/patients', patient).success(function(data){
            for(var i = 0; i < object.patients.length; i++) {
                if(object.patients[i].id == patient.id) {
                    object.patients.splice(i, 1);
                }
        });
```

Something like that maybe, hard to say without knowing the response. If the response (data) is the deleted patient then you can use "if(object.patients[i].id == **data**.id)" instead

Comment: I uploaded the reponse data. Does that make more sense? :) Thanks for answering. Also trying to use what you posted. I'll let you know!